# ASP.NET - Access HTML Attributes On Runtime

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to use jquery-tagthis plugin in asp.net page.
everything work fine, but i cant access html attribute on runtime!

jQuery plugin make a html attribute with "data-value" name.
When i access the attribute on runtime, its null!
When i define this attribute on aspx code, i can access the attribute with initial value, not changed value by jquery.
I check the html code on browser, its look fine and everything is ok, but on server side, i have initialized value.
i check the Page_Load and other event and i couldnt find and problem or value.

I used asp:Panel insted of div with runat="server" but it dosent change anything!

ASPX Code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Tags" runat="server" data-value="test" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Panel>
```

jQuery changing value (work fine, because i see the new value on browser when use the developers tools)

```
$("#Tags").attr('data-value', commadelimitedTags);
```

And C# Code Behind:

```
string t = Tags.Attributes["data-value"];
```

In Page_Load and ASP:Button On Click Event, its return only "test" value!

Comment: `data-attribute` tags are used to _store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements_. Did you try `$("#Tags").data('value')`? Also which version of .net you're using?

Comment: This is expected behavior. If you want to return values to the server without displaying them to the user, use HiddenFields.

Comment: finally i use the asp:hiddenfield, but i am curious to know why data not passed to server. and now i know this is asp.net behavior. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes of html elements are never posted to the server.

You need to do the following:

Firstly, on your "save" button, do not put any .NET OnClick method. Only put a javascript method calling a save function.

Secondly, in the save function, find all your attributes and put them in hidden fields. If the content is dynamic, perhaps you want to serialize it to json and put it in a single hidden field.

Thirdly, invoke the click event of a button where you've attached a .NET event with `$('#buttonId').click()`. Inside this event you will be able to find the contents of the hidden field.

Comment: thanks for you best solution, i use this solution to pass attribute to server.

Answer (score 0):

**The attributes** on the page elements (like a div) **are NOT Posted Back**, so the code behind can not read the changes that you may make using javascript.

So you can set them on code behind, but if you changes them with javascript, there are not posted back to code behind.

To send values on code behind use the `HiddenField`, set there your values and then read it on code behind.

Comment: thanks for your solution. its works good. 
unfortunatly asp.net dosent pass html attribute to server. i make the attribute by code on page_load event, but dosent change anything! BAD ASP.NET :)

Comment: @MehdiRizvandi Look, the attributes did not pass to server because of the browsers. asp.net have nothing to do with this.

Comment: well, you right. then BAD Browser ;)
 thanks for your comment.